# If a product space is metrisable, are the factor spaces metrisable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, product-space

Let $((E_i,\mathcal O_i))_{i\in I}$ be an at most countable family of topological spaces, each containing at least two distinct elements. Let $E=\prod_{i\in I}E_i$ and $\mathcal O$ be the product topology on $E$.

It is well known that if each $E_i$ is metrisable, then $E$ is metrisable.

**Is the converse true?** That is if $E$ is metrisable, is $E_i$ metrisable for all $i\in I$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, because each $E_j$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\prod_{i\in I}E_i$. And a subspace of a metrizable space is metrizable.

Comment: Right, thanks! :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @Will note that this holds for any size index set $I$. Not only countable ones. To go from all $E_i$ metrisable to the product being metrisable, we need a countable index set.

Comment: An uncountably infinite product cannot be metrisable (if the factor spaces contain at least two elements each). So it is true that if such a product is metrisable, then all the factor spaces are metrisable. But it is like saying something like "if $0=1$ then [statement]".